# ETFs from Ireland and Luxembourg

Tags: etf, china, interactive-brokers, ireland, brazil

From [Nonresident alien's ETF domicile decision table](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Nonresident_alien%27s_ETF_domicile_decision_table):

"Ireland is the most common domicile for non-US domiciled ETFs, although Luxembourg is another popular non-US domicile for ETFs"

"In general then, if avoiding US domiciled ETFs you should prefer Ireland domiciled ETFs over Luxembourg domiciled ones unless the ETF itself holds no US stocks."

Sounds like non US residents should buy from Ireland or Luxembourg.

For whom (among the non US residents) is the 2nd (general) statement correct? For whom or when is Luxembourg better? If you hold Luxembourg citizenship should you buy from Lux?

Comment: It doesn't say that you should buy *from* Ireland or Luxembourg. It says that you should consider buying Ireland or Luxembourg *domiciled* ETFs.

Comment: I suggest that you do some reading of Investopedia articles about ETFs, and read all the Bogleheads wiki pages for non-US residents. That way, you will be in a better position to ask questions about your particular situation, and have the background to understand the answers.

Comment: The funds/ETFs do some taxation themselves. Some taxes are lower in Ireland than Luxembourg thus more money stays in the fund.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Brazilian resident, you have a tax advantage to buy Ireland domiciled ETFs as long as they are accumulating rather than distributing dividends.
Receive dividends is less "tax efetive" compared to selling stock(for brazilians). Why? You have to pay tax on the dividends as normal income in the current Brazilian tax code (December 2022) which can go as high as 27,5%. Even if you don't pay at the moment you receive it you will have to pay in your yearly tax income declaration.
If you sell a foreign stock, you can end up in two situations: 1- If you sell less than 35k R$/month in foreign you are 100% exempt of any tax. 2- If you sell above 35k R$/month you have to pay 15% of your gains.

And why Ireland domiciled ETFS are better than US? Because 1- US domiciled ETFs always distribute dividends and make you pay 30% tax on the dividends 2- Us domiciled ETFs dividends are taxed 30% for Brazilians while the dividend received by Ireland domiciled ETFs are only taxed 15%.

The Ireland domiciled ETF advantage is only applicable if you chose ETFs that do not distribute dividends. If for some reason you do chose to receive dividends then you actually have a tax disadvantage.

Sorry for the broken English.